# Trying to run a script with Express on localhost:3000

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

Stuck on my first attempt at a basic app. Scraper.js scrapes a URL and writes the returned array to the document obj when run alone in console, so that part works. Now all I want is an Express server to run the script whenever I open localhost:3000 but not sure how to do so.

```
|node_modules
|package.json
|public
|-index.html  (boilerplate HTML. Not importing anything)
|src
|-scraper.js
|index.js
```

index.js:

```
var scraperjs = require('scraperjs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express()

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(3000);
```

--

scraper.js:

```
scraperjs.StaticScraper.create('https://examplesite.com/')
    .scrape(function($) {
        return $(".entry-content p").map(function() {
              var content =  $(this).html();
              return content
            }
       }).get();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        ... // eventually will write the items returned from the data array to div's
        } 
 });
```

Comment: If you are just using vanilla JS, you can add a window.onload event and use fetch to reach the express route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to export the scraperjs function using `module.exports = functionName()` as the last line in scraper.js.

Your `require` in index.js needs to factor in the path location for scraper.js.  So:

`var scraperjs = require('./src/scraperjs');`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a one that i've coded with promises, and also using a global variable which is `daNews`

```
var scraperjs = require('scraperjs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var url = 'https://news.ycombinator.com/';
var daNews;

function myScraper(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    scraperjs.StaticScraper.create(url)
        .scrape(function($) {
            return $(".title a").map(function() {
                return $(this).text();
            }).get();
        })
        .then(function(news) {
            daNews = news;
            resolve('done');
      })
    });
}

app.get('/', function(req, res){

  async function m1(){
    var x = await myScraper();
    if(x == 'done'){
      res.send(daNews);
    }else{
      console.log('err');
    }
  }

  m1();

})

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: comment on why you dislike!